# RecyclerView with users is empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to make a chat app using Firebase and Android Studio.I'm using a RecyclerView to view all the users with only their FirstName in the firebase database but everytime is empty.Can somebody show me what modifies to do?

This is how my database looks like.
![1]https://imgur.com/a/U06syNe

I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.Tried a lot of tutorials from github.

The UsersActivity class is where is the RecyclerView and the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView userslist;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private List<Users> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_users );
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ().child ( "users" );


        userslist = (RecyclerView) findViewById ( R.id.users_list );


        userslist.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this ) );


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        super.onStart ();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users> ()
                .setQuery ( ref, Users.class )
                .build ();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, FindFriendViewHolder> ( options ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder findFriendViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Users users) {
                findFriendViewHolder.userName.setText ( users.getName () );

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.users_template, parent, false );
                FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder ( view );
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        userslist.setAdapter ( adapter );
        adapter.startListening ();
    }

    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userName;
        ImageView profileImage;

        public FindFriendViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );
            userName = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.username1 );
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.profilepicture );

        }


    }
}
```

This is my model for Users

```
public class Users {
    public String name;
    public Users(){}
    public Users(String name){
    this.name=name;}
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

The gradle looks like this(i'm using androidx)

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.2'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

I expect to fetch the data from the database and stores in the RecyclerView to show all my users.

Comment: Can you confirm if **onBindViewHolder()** is called and if  **users.getName ()** has no empty value?

Comment: Yes.When I open the activity nothing appears and I'm having 3 users already in the database.And all users have their firstname in the database.

Comment: I tried to open your database structure from this link https://imgur.com/a/U06syNe but not is shown

Comment: Yes. Won't let me to upload. My structure is that I have a node named users and under are the primary keys for every users and under every primary key is the first name and the second name.

Comment: Ok, so try change the field **public String name;** to **public String firstName;** in your Users model, maybe the firebase parser is looking for a firstName in your model.

Comment: didn't work this.

Comment: Have you tried to make the fields in your `Users` class private? Please add a screenshot that can be seen and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

There is no getitemcount() method shown in the code. It is absolutely necessary to implement that method inside recyclerview.

Comment: Where to put?New to recyclerview.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java